# Splitting text and converting linq

Tags: c#, linq

I have a string array and want to convert it to double array with LINQ. I don't want to use `foreach` loops.

```
var texts = new List<string> 
{"-87.98 65", "-86.98 75", "-97.98 78", "-81.98 65"}
```

To:

```
var numerics = new List<IEnumerable<double>> 
{
     new List<double>{-87.98, 65},
     new List<double>{86.98, 75},
     new List<double>{-97.98 78},
     new List<double>{-81.98 65}
}
```

Is there any short way with LINQ?

Comment: This is my preference.  Notice I use ToList() twice :             var texts = new List<string> { "-87.98 65", "-86.98 75", "-97.98 78", "-81.98 65" };

            List<List<double>> results = texts.Select(x => new List<double>(x.Split(new char[] {' '}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Select(y => double.Parse(y)).ToList())).ToList();

Answer (score 7):

You could use this:

```
var doubles = texts.Select(x => x.Split()
                                 .Select(y => double.Parse(y, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
                                 .ToList()
                                 .AsEnumerable() // added to comply to the desired signature
                          )
                   .ToList() // added to comply to the desired signature
                   ;
```

It first selects the string, splits it on spaces, and then parses the strings in the string array to doubles. That output is converted to a list.

Comment: I think `x.Split(' ')` would be enough, no need to use the array form.

Comment: I think x.Split() would be enough

Comment: Not a fan of method group use? `.Select(double.Parse)`

Comment: To get the OP's desired type of `List<IEnumerable<double>>`  you'd need to move that `ToList` out of the `Select`.

Comment: @PatrickHofman true but right now `doubles` is a `IEnumerable` and not a `List` itself.  In the long run it probably doesn't matter anyway.

Comment: Ah, you are right. I was focussing on the inner, not the outer. Will update.

Comment: @juharr this should do now. Tested it against the desired output type.

Comment: Hate to make a mess of all the cleanup this answer has gotten, but this solution does not work on my machine, To be sure that this works everywhere it would be advisable to change the double parse method to include `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture`.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
var texts = new List<string> { "-87.98 65", "-86.98 75", "-97.98 78", "-81.98 65" };

List<List<double>> newList = 
  texts.Select(t => t.Split(' ').Select(s => Convert.ToDouble(s)).ToList()).ToList();

foreach (var item in newList)
   foreach (var item2 in item)
      Console.Write(item2 + "  ;");
```

Output : `-87,98;   65;  -86,98; 75; -97,98; 78; -81,98; 65;`

But i wouldn't call it 'a short way'...

Answer (score 0):

This fits the signature:

```
var texts = new List<string> {"-87.98 65", "-86.98 75", "-97.98 78", "-81.98 65"};

List<IEnumerable<double>> numerics = 
     texts.Select(s => new List<double>(s.Split().Select(sub => Double.Parse(sub, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))))
          .Cast<IEnumerable<double>>()
          .ToList();
```